# How can i configure sql connection for several instances in gorm v2 using db-resolver

Tags: go, go-gorm

I am using gorm.io/gorm and gorm.io/plugin/dbresolver for my project. How can I configure MaxIdleConns, MaxOpenConns, ConnMaxIdleTime and ConnMaxLifetime most correctly for each connection?

```
db, _ := gorm.Open(postgres.Open(config.GetConnectArgs()), &gorm.Config{})

replicas := make([]gorm.Dialector, len(config.GetReplicasConfig()))

for i, cfg := range config.GetReplicasConfig() {
    replicas[i] = postgres.Open(cfg.GetConnectArgs())
}

resolver := dbresolver.Register(dbresolver.Config{
    Replicas: replicas,
    Policy:   dbresolver.RandomPolicy{},
})

_ = db.Use(resolver)


dbConfig, _ := db.DB()
dbConfig.SetMaxOpenConns(0)
dbConfig.SetMaxIdleConns(10)
dbConfig.SetConnMaxLifetime(time.Hour)
```

Will this code only return a single connection?

```
dbConfig, _ := db.DB()
dbConfig.SetMaxOpenConns(0)
dbConfig.SetMaxIdleConns(10)
dbConfig.SetConnMaxLifetime(time.Hour)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolver can configure connections for the entire pool

```
db, _ := gorm.Open(postgres.Open(config.GetConnectArgs()), &gorm.Config{})

replicas := make([]gorm.Dialector, len(config.GetReplicasConfig()))

for i, cfg := range config.GetReplicasConfig() {
    replicas[i] = postgres.Open(cfg.GetConnectArgs())
}

resolver := dbresolver.Register(dbresolver.Config{
    Replicas: replicas,
    Policy:   dbresolver.RandomPolicy{},
}).
   SetMaxOpenConns(0).
   SetMaxIdleConns(10).
   SetConnMaxLifetime(time.Hour)

_ = db.Use(resolver)
```

It was written in the documentation. Sorry for the stupid question.